# Android Volley doesn't load data from the Server after recreating of the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-volley

I have one big problem that is bugging me for a couple of days right now. In the application I am working on, I have couple of activities, and one of them is central (BaseActivity) from which the app goes to other Activities and in each of them it works with Volley Library to fetch data from the API.

So for instance, if I go from BaseActivity to SelectionActivity, in SelectionActivity I receive my recycle view with all the necessary data. That is quite alright, that's what I need.

However, when I finish the activity either by clicking back button or home button on the toolbar, and then want to return back to the SelectionActivity again, the data is not being loaded again. It doesn't state any exception, just doesn't load anything.

I have been searching all over the Internet but I can't seem to find the solution.

EDIT: OK further when I investigated with the debugger. It seems like everything should work because it goes through the response, and through everything. However, instead of RecyclerView filled with data, I don't see anything.

SelectionController Method:

```
public void getAllJobs()
{
    queue = VolleyRequestHandler.getInstance(false).getQueue();

    JsonArrayRequest jobsRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,makeAllJobsRequest(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
                    Job job;
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i=0; i<response.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject dbJob = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            job = new Job();

                            job.setId(dbJob.getLong("JobId"));
                            job.setName(dbJob.getString("JobText"));
                            job.setCustName(dbJob.getString("CustomerName"));

                            jobs.add(job);
                        }

                        // Entries are being sorted!
                        Collections.sort(jobs, new CustomerComparator());

                        injection.onGettingAllJobs(jobs);
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        injection.onErrorSelection(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            injection.onErrorSelection(error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    jobsRequest.setTag(injection.GET_JOBS_TAG);

    jobsRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10),//time out in 10second
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,//DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 1;
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    queue.add(jobsRequest);
}
```

SelectionInjection interface:

```
public interface SelectionInjection
{
    public static final String GET_JOBS_TAG = "SELECTION_GET_JOBS_TAG";
    public static final String GET_TASKS_TAG = "SELECTION_GET_TASKS_TAG";
    public static final String SAVE_ENTRY_TAG ="SELECTION_SAVE_ENTRY_TAG";

    public void onGettingAllJobs(List<Job> jobs);

    public void onGettingTasksForJob(List<Task> tasks);

    public void onSavedEntry(TimeEntry savedEntry);

    public void onErrorSelection(String message);
}
```

SelectionActivity:

```
public class SelectionActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SelectionInjection {

    private static final String TAG = SelectionActivity.class.getName();

    /*
    * Init variables for Recycler Views
    * */
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private SelectJobAdapter mJobsAdapter;
    private StickyHeadersItemDecoration headers;
    private SelectTaskAdapter mSelectTaskAdapter;

    /*
    * Lists used for adapter and for storing information from server
    * */
    private List<Job> mJobs;
    private List<Task> mTasks;
    private SelectionController controller;
    private Job selectedJob;


    // Inject Views with ButterKnife
    @InjectView(R.id.select_job_recyclerview) SuperRecyclerView mJobSuperRecyclerView;
    @InjectView(R.id.select_task_recyclerview) SuperRecyclerView mTaskSuperRecyclerView;
    @InjectView(R.id.job_view)FrameLayout mJobView;
    @InjectView(R.id.task_view) FrameLayout mTaskView;
    @InjectView(R.id.toolbar_actionbar) Toolbar mToolbarAction;

    private int mAnimDuration;
//    private SelectionTask mFetchingTask; // Is it a good idea to Init it here? -> Nej
//    private SaveSelectionTask mSavingTask;


    // TODO: Figure out why after coming back again to this activity, there is only a loading wheel and nothing shows up
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        /*
        *  Setting up stuff for ViewSwitching
        * */
        mTaskView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Also set in XMl but just in case :D
        mAnimDuration = getResources()
                .getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime);
        /*
        * Setting Up Action Bar
        * */
        mToolbarAction.setTitle(getString(R.string.select_job_title));
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbarAction);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); // Hierarchical activity

        if (mJobs == null) {
            // provifing dummy test data
            Log.v(TAG, "mJobs are are null");
//            mJobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
//            List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
//            taskList.add(
//                    new Task(88,"Task Name Doh")
//                    );
//            taskList.add(
//                    new Task(99,"Another Task Name Doh")
//            );
//            mJobs.add(
//                    new Job(
//                            10,
//                            "Test Job",
//                            1337,
//                            "Fake Customer",
//                            taskList
//                            ));
            fetchJobs();
        }
        else
        {
            setUpJobRecyclerView();
        }
    }



    private void fetchJobs() {
        Log.v(TAG,"fetchJobs();");
//        mFetchingTask = new SelectionTask();
//        mFetchingTask.execute(); // No PAram, get all the jobs
        controller = SelectionController.getInstance(BaseActivity.currentUser,this);
        controller.getAllJobs();
    }

    private void fetchTasks(Job job){
        Log.v(TAG,"fetchTAsks()");
        try{
//            mFetchingTask = new SelectionTask();
//            mFetchingTask.execute(job);

            controller = SelectionController.getInstance(BaseActivity.currentUser,this);
            controller.getTasksForJob(job);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.v(TAG,"There was an error fetching tasks");
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this,"There was error fetching tasks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Method for setting up Job Recycler View
     */
    private void setUpJobRecyclerView(){
        /*
        * Setting up Jobs Recycler View
        * */
        mJobsAdapter = new SelectJobAdapter(mJobs);
        mJobsAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        headers = new StickyHeadersBuilder()
                .setAdapter(mJobsAdapter)
                .setRecyclerView(mJobSuperRecyclerView.getRecyclerView())
                .setStickyHeadersAdapter(new SelectJobHeaderAdapter(mJobs))
                .build();

        mJobSuperRecyclerView.setAdapter(mJobsAdapter);
        mJobSuperRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(headers);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mJobSuperRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        // Setting up onClickListener
        mJobSuperRecyclerView.
                addOnItemTouchListener(
                        new RecyclerUtils.RecyclerItemClickListener(
                                this,
                                new RecyclerUtils.RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                        selectedJob = mJobs.get(position);
                                        showMaterialDialog(position);
                                    }
                                }));
    }
    /**
    * Method used for settigng up and initalising all the adapters
     * for TaskRecyclerView
    * */
    private void setUpTaskRecyclerView() {
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mTaskSuperRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mSelectTaskAdapter = new SelectTaskAdapter(mTasks);
        mSelectTaskAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        headers = new StickyHeadersBuilder()
                .setAdapter(mSelectTaskAdapter)
                .setRecyclerView(mTaskSuperRecyclerView.getRecyclerView())
                .setStickyHeadersAdapter(new SelectTaskHeaderAdapter(mTasks))
                .build();

        mTaskSuperRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSelectTaskAdapter);
        mTaskSuperRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(headers);
        mTaskSuperRecyclerView.
                addOnItemTouchListener(
                        new RecyclerUtils.RecyclerItemClickListener(
                                this,
                                new RecyclerUtils.RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                        Log.v(TAG,"TaskRecyclerView onItemClick");
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The Task has been added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                                        mSavingTask = new SaveSelectionTask();
//                                        mSavingTask.execute(mTasks.get(position));
                                    }
                                }));

    }

    /**
     * A method that starts a corssfade Animation between JobView and TaskView
     *
     */
    private void crossfadeViews(final View fromView, View toView){
        // Set the Task view to 0% opacity but visible, so that it is visible
        // (but fully transparent) during the animation.
        toView.setAlpha(0f);
        toView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Animate the Task view to 100% opacity, and clear any animation
        // listener set on the view.
        toView.animate()
                .alpha(1f)
                .setDuration(mAnimDuration)
                .setListener(null);

        // Animate the Job view to 0% opacity. After the animation ends,
        // set its visibility to GONE as an optimization step (it won't
        // participate in layout passes, etc.)
        fromView.animate()
                .alpha(0f)
                .setDuration(mAnimDuration)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        fromView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates and shows a Dialog
     * and executes fetchTasks() if given option is picked.
     */
    private void showMaterialDialog(final int position){
        // TODO: Consider starting running he Async Task straight away as
        //       it might be likely that the user will pick "Pcik A Task" option
        //       and this might speed up the process
        Log.v(TAG,"showMAterialDialog");
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title("Choose Action")
                .positiveText("Add Job")
                .negativeText("Pick A Task")
                .neutralText("CANCEL")
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        // Add Job
                        Log.v(TAG,"Adding the whole Job");
//                        mSavingTask = new SaveSelectionTask();
//                        mSavingTask.execute();
                        controller = SelectionController.getInstance(BaseActivity.currentUser,SelectionActivity.this);
                        controller.saveNewTimeEntry(BaseActivity.selectedDate,selectedJob,null);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        /**
                         *Pick a Task
                         */
                        fetchTasks(mJobs.get(position));
                        Log.v(TAG, "Switching Views");
                        crossfadeViews(mJobView, mTaskView);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNeutral(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        Log.v(TAG,"Cancelling the Dialog Choice");

                    }
                }).show();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.global, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        try
        {
            switch(id)
            {
                case R.id.action_settings:

                    return true;
                case android.R.id.home:
                    if (mTaskView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    {
                        crossfadeViews(mTaskView,mJobView);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSavedEntry(TimeEntry savedEntry)
    {
        Log.v("SAVED ENTRY", "TRUE");
        System.out.println(savedEntry.toString());
        controller.closeQueue(SAVE_ENTRY_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGettingAllJobs(List<Job> jobs) {
        mJobs = jobs;
        setUpJobRecyclerView();
        controller.closeQueue(GET_JOBS_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGettingTasksForJob(List<Task> tasks) {
        mTasks = tasks;
        setUpTaskRecyclerView();
        controller.closeQueue(GET_TASKS_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorSelection(String message) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onErrorJobTask");
    }
}
```

Comment: call that service/method on onResume() override method of that particular Activity

Comment: the problem is not that the method is not being called... problem is that I don't get the callback..

Comment: try invalidate your view... if response is comming ..then it might be the case where view needs to refresh

Comment: I understand but I wouldn't get why is it happening? I mean I destroyed the activity once, and then create a new one.... why would the view stay there?

Comment: I tried to invalidate the view, still nothing

Comment: Where in your Activities do you call getAllJobs() ? Please post the codes of your Activities where you call this method.  And what is injection ? If your RecyclerView is empty, it probably has something to do with this injection.

Comment: do some trick...create on argument (hardcoded json in place of response json) for getAllJobs method ..and then check...

Comment: onresponse call pass that argument intead of response string

Comment: I have already checked with the debugger I received the jobs I need and even assign it to the adapter, etc... otherwise it would have thrown me a NullPointerException...

Comment: So injection refers to listeners. This is what you should debug next. Find the implementations of onGettingAllJobs and onErrorSelection and put break points there. See if those points are reached. My diagnosis is this: there is a race condition between your http calls and activity creation, the activity that holds the implementation of these listeners. When the data arrive the layout is not yet built so the data go to nowhere and you end up seeing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging, I have come across to the solution:

It seemed like the way I was making Controllers and Injections didn't really fit into the Android development so I have restructured the code back into the activities and fragments and all works now.

EDIT:

Finally I have figured out what the ACTUAL problem is. When I was passing the Context to the Controller.. I only did so when I actually instantiated them. And because Controllers are singletons in my case, I have been using the old context when reentering Activity.

I can't believe how I did not get that. :)